# Spork error in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork

```
Using RSpec, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:26:in `initialize'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:26:in `new'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:26:in `sqlite3_connection'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:796:in `current_version'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:804:in `needs_migration?'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `check_pending!'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in preload'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-rails-4.0.0/lib/spork/app_framework/rails.rb:8:in `preload'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:134:in `block in preload'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork.rb:62:in `exec_prefork'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:120:in `preload'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:25:in `preload'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork/runner.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
/Users/me/Desktop/rails_stuff/rails_projects/sample_app/vendor/bundle/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/spork:23:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/spork:23:in `<main>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The error seems to happen when preparing the testing db, have you tried to run tests without Spork first?

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your question so that future users can see what issues you specifically had and how you fixed them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... corrupt bundle.  I needed to rebuild my bundle after upgrading from Mac OS 10.8 to 10.9.  I deleted my vendor\bundle directory and ran bundle install.

Comment: So you should probably mark this as answered and add some descriptive text to help others who might face the same issue, or delete it entirely if it of no use to others.

Comment: I deleted my vendor\bundle directory and ran bundle install